# Positioning div in center css

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to add a div block so that it's at the center of the screen. All i have is a fixed background image and it's doing some odd stuff.

CSS:

```
body {               
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

#middle {       <--- the white div block
    background-color:#FFF;
    display:block;
    width:750px;
    height:750px;
    margin:0 auto 0 auto;
    margin-top:15px;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
}

#bigbg {                <-- background image
    height:auto;
    width:100%;
    z-index:-100;
    min-height:100%;
    min-width:100%;
    margin-left:0%;
    position:fixed;
    margin-top:0px;
}
```

html:

```
<div id='middle'>
</div>
<img src="images/backgroundmain.jpg" id="bigbg">
```

Looks like this:
[image: looks like this]

i want the white div block to be centered in the middle. Is there a better way of applying a background image? I was able to achieve what i wanted by adding the `background-image:url` property to the html, but i wasn't able to add all the properties i wanted such as fixed margins/width etc..

Comment: ok so i managed to get the div positioned in the middle however if i add a top margin it puts a white strip between the top margin and the block: http://i.imgur.com/qn15ppN.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Change `margin:0 auto 0 auto;` to `margin:0px auto;` in the middle class

Comment: `margin: 0 auto 0 auto` and `margin: 0px auto` are equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Upadate your css a below

```
body {               
margin:0;
padding:0;
width=100%;
}

#middle {       <--- the white div block
background-color:#FFF;
display:block;
width:750px;
height:750px;
margin:15px auto 0 auto;
position:relative;
overflow:hidden;
}

#bigbg {                <-- background image
height:auto;
width:100%;
z-index:-100;
min-height:100%;
min-width:100%;
margin-left:0%;
position:fixed;
margin-top:0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

to the 'middle' div add `margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;`

or you could do something like this:

```
body {
width: 100%; <---make sure you use percentages
height: 100% <---          
margin:0;
padding:0;
}

#middle {       
background-color:#FFF;
display:block;
width:25%; <--change the width and height to % also
height:25%; <---
left: 37.5%; <--since your div is 25% wide you want to move 
<--- it 37% to the right to center it. (100% - 25% = 75% / 2 = 37.5%)
margin:0 auto 0 auto;
margin-top:15px;
position:relative;
overflow:hidden;
}

#bigbg {                <-- background image
height:auto;
width:100%;
z-index:-100;
min-height:100%;
min-width:100%;
margin-left:0%;
position:fixed;
margin-top:0px;
}
```

However, if you're keeping your code the same, i'd suggest just switching `margin:0 auto 0 auto;` to `margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;`

Comment: ok so i managed to get the div positioned in the middle however if i add a top margin it puts a white strip between the top margin and the block: i.imgur.com/qn15ppN.jpg

Comment: that's because you have margin-top: set to 15px. try `top: 37.5%`